# Problem with height:auto on bootstrap modal after Jquery upgrade

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a weird problem, I was using JQuery 1.7 with bootstrap 3.6 and everything worked normally. I am having some bootstrap modals that pops-up on click, showing information from database. The modal was having height:auto so it always had the correct height based on the amount of information it opened.

Then I had upgraded the JQuery to latest version, as well as bootstrap to 3.7.

After that, the height:auto is no longer working correctly. Which means, sometimes it is set to :auto and works correctly, sometimes it gets set to some random value (like 667px).

Nothing else was touched and / or modifed. I tried to revert the upgrades and I noticed that the upgrade where it broken is starting from some version like JQuery 3.2 or something, until that it works perfectly.

Any clue what could've have changed in JQuery to make a modal height:auto not working all times and instead setting some random values to the height?

Thanks!

#Edit
This is the pop-up code that was working perfectly before JQuery upgrade:

```
info_pop_up: function (title,character,server,wdth) 
    {
        var w = 'auto';
        if (typeof(wdth) == "undefined") 
        {
            w = 470;
        }
        
            $('.jBox-wrapper').each(function() {
                if ($(this).attr('id').startsWith('jBox')) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });
            var MyjBox =  new jBox('Modal', {
            width: w,
            height: 'auto',
            closeButton: 'title',
            animation: false,
            blockScroll: false,
            adjustTracker: true,
            title: title,
            draggable : 'title',
            overlay :0,

                ajax: {
                    url: Website.base_url + 'ajax/char-info',
                    data: {
                        'type': 'char_info', 'character':character, 'server':server
                    },
                    dataType: 'html',
                    reload: 'strict',

                    setContent: false,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        this.setContent('');
                        this.setTitle('<div class="ajax-complete"><i class="icons icon-enter" style="float:left;margin-top:10px;margin-left:20px;"></i>'+title+'</div>');
                    },
                    complete: function(response) {
                        this.setTitle('<div class="ajax-complete"><i class="icons icon-enter" style="float:left;margin-top:10px;margin-left:20px;"></i>'+title+'</div>');
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        this.setContent(response);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        this.setContent('<div class="ajax-error">Oops, something went wrong</div>');
                    }
                }
            });
        return MyjBox.open();
    }
```

Comment: Where is your code !?

Comment: Sorry, added the pop-up code